# Getting within and in-between variances and lambda ratio with MIcombine?

Tags: r, survey, imputation, variance, r-mice

I'm pooling estimates from a raking weighting procedure on multiple imputed data and I'm interested in describing how the variability from the imputation by chained equation carry over my estimates. I want to do this by reporting [U-hat (i.e.: the average within variance of the estimate), B (the in-between variance or the extra variance caused by the fact that there is missing data in the sample) and λ (i.e.: the proportion of total variance due to missingness or the ratio of the B on the total variance)](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-whyandwhen.html#sec:threesources).

These parameters are usually easily accessible with the [pool() function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mice/versions/3.16.0/topics/pool) from `mice` package. However, I'm using `MIcombine` because [it is more convenient if we want to apply raking procedure to multiple imputed data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42637406/raking-multiple-imputed-dataset).

So my question is : how can I get the within and in-between variances and the lambda ratio from `MIcombine`?

Here is a reproducible code.

```
library(mitools)
library(survey)
library(mice)

data(nhanes)

nhanes2$hyp <- as.factor(nhanes2$hyp)

imp <- mice(nhanes2,method=c("polyreg","pmm","logreg","pmm"), seed = 23109)

imp_list <- lapply( 1:5 , function( n ) complete( imp , action = n ) )


des<-svydesign(id=~1, data=imputationList(imp_list))
small.svy.rake<-des


age.dist <- data.frame(age =  c("20-39","40-59", "60-99"),
                       Freq = nrow(des) * c(0.5, 0.3, .2))

# loop through each of the implicates
# applying the `rake` function to each
small.svy.rake$designs <- 
  lapply( 
    des$designs , 
    rake ,
    sample.margins = list(~age),
    population.margins = list(age.dist)
  )

# new mean bmi estimated after raking with pooled standard error
summary(MIcombine( with( small.svy.rake , svymean( ~ bmi ) ) ))
```

Within standard error can be extract from the list of raking operations on the imputed data

```
rake.list<-with( des , svymean( ~ bmi ) )#create a list object

datalong<-do.call(rbind, lapply(rake.list , function(x) data.frame(x)))#transform into long format data frame

mean(datalong[,2]) #mean standard error=within standard error
```

However, I don't know how to obtain the two other components, i.e.: the in-between variance and the lambda parameter and would enjoy any help to get closer to that goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Thomas Lumley comment, here are the adjustments to print the in-between variance and the lambda ratio:

```
MIcombine_addparam<-function (results, variances, call = sys.call(), df.complete = Inf, 
          ...) 
{
  m <- length(results)
  oldcall <- attr(results, "call")
  if (missing(variances)) {
    variances <- suppressWarnings(lapply(results, vcov))
    results <- lapply(results, coef)
  }
  vbar <- variances[[1]]
  cbar <- results[[1]]
  for (i in 2:m) {
    cbar <- cbar + results[[i]]
    vbar <- vbar + variances[[i]]
  }
  cbar <- cbar/m
  vbar <- vbar/m
  evar <- var(do.call("rbind", results))
  r <- (1 + 1/m) * evar/vbar
  df <- (m - 1) * (1 + 1/r)^2
  if (is.matrix(df)) 
    df <- diag(df)
  if (is.finite(df.complete)) {
    dfobs <- ((df.complete + 1)/(df.complete + 3)) * df.complete * 
      vbar/(vbar + evar)
    if (is.matrix(dfobs)) 
      dfobs <- diag(dfobs)
    df <- 1/(1/dfobs + 1/df)
  }
  if (is.matrix(r)) 
    r <- diag(r)
  rval <- list(coefficients = cbar, variance = vbar + evar * 
                 (m + 1)/m,B=evar,lambda=r/(r+1), call = c(oldcall, call), nimp = m, df = df, 
               missinfo = (r + 2/(df + 3))/(r + 1))
  class(rval) <- "MIresult"
  rval
}
```

In-between variance is computed directly by the function so we retain `evar` as B in the output. For the proportion of variance due to missingness, the function computes the ratio `r`, which is the relative increase in variance due to nonresponse. [Following Van Buuren](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-whyandwhen.html#sec:threesources), it is linked to `lambda` by r=λ/(1−λ), so can be solved for `lambda` by λ=r/(r+1).

Answer (score 1):

`MIcombine` doesn't return this information, but it does internally compute all the parts you need.  You can look at the code: `mitools:::MIcombine.default` and modify the function to return more things